# Scala function call

Tags: function, scala, parameters

I have found following function calls in several frameworks which appear to me as if the framework extends some base classes. Some examples:

```
within(500 millis)
```

or

```
"Testcase description" in
  { .... }
```

First example returns a duration object with the duration of 500 milliseconds from akka and second is the definition of a testcase from scalatest.

I would like to know how this behavior is achieved and how it is called.

Comment: This behavior is done by [implicit conversions](http://bit.ly/iMy6I1). On SO there are some questions about it, search after `pimp-my-library`.

Comment: The title of your question could be more descriptive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is done with the "[Pimp my library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766)" [technique](http://scala.sygneca.com/patterns/pimp-my-library).

To add non existing methods to a class, you define an implicit method that converts objects of that class to objects of a class that has the method:

```
class Units(i: Int) {
  def millis = i
}

implicit def toUnits(i: Int) = new Units(i)


class Specs(s: String) {
  def in(thunk: => Unit) = thunk
}

implicit def toSpecs(s: String) = new Specs(s)
```

See also ["Where does Scala looks for Implicits?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-looks-for-implicits)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, those pieces of code can be desugared as

```
within(500.millis)
```

and

```
"Testcase description".in({ ... })
```

This should make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, i know but then the class Integer must have a member "millis" or String needs to have "in" which they don't have

Comment: @Sebastian: My guess is there is some sort of implicit conversion going on, but my Scala-fu isn't up to that level yet, so I'm not sure.